# Винительный или родительный падеж?

Tags: падежи, недопустимая-метка

Совсем запуталась. Как правильно:

- ...не расширяют коронарные(х) сосуды(ов);
- ...не угнетают дыхательные(х) и сосудодвигательные(х) центры(ов);
- ...не суживает коронарные(х) артерии(й); не нарушает обмен(а) углеводов;
- ...не провоцируют подъем(а) АД и т.п.

Какое применяется правило? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется, правильно "не расширяет коронарные сосуды" и т.д. Это винительный падеж существительных, отвечающий на вопрос "кого, что?". Коронарные сосуды - неодушевленный предмет, поэтому отвечает на вопрос "что?".

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны.
Тут дело не в одушевленности/неодушевленности, а в том что с "не" возможен как винительный, так и родительный падежи.
В научном тексте винительный падеж предпочтительнее, но не императивно.