# Решения или решение?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте. Как правильно в подобных конструкциях: "ждет решение" или "ждет решения"? Вроде правилен первый вариант, так как винительный падеж. Но часто встречается и второй.

Answer (score 2):

Про выбор родительного или винительного падежа уже неоднократно говорилось на этом форуме, например **[здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5536/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-vs-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6), [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/363/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)** и ещё **[много где](https://rus.stackexchange.com/search/?q=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&t=question).**
В варианте *"ждет решение"* без контекста получается, что это сказуемое и подлежащее (так как винительный и именительный падеж совпадают, их сложно отличить), поэтому предпочтительнее второй вариант. Если честно, то мне вообще сложно представить употребление винительного падежа в вашем примере.